# Why I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Google Drive Api.?

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I tried integrating google API in my VB.NET project.
I am getting the error Object reference not set to an Instance of an object.
But if I run the same thing again it works.

My code:

```
Try
        Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)
        request.Upload()
        Dim responsefile = request.ResponseBody
        MsgBox(responsefile.Id.ToString) '-----Error catch here 
Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
        Return Nothing
End Try
```

**NOTE : The same thing I run 2nd time in and it works well.**

What should I do?

Comment: That error usually suggest that `responsefile` was set to nothing e.g `request.responseBody` was null. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exactly what it says, you are trying to use a null object as if it was a properly referenced object. Most of the time, when you try to assing value into object, and if the value is null, then this kind of exception occur.

Comment: @K.Madden What shall I do?
I can't add a `new` there.

Comment: could you try setting it to `nothing`?

Comment: @K.Madden Tried this, ain't worked.. :(...
`Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = Nothing | 
                    request = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)`

Comment: @K.Madden Any other Idea?

Comment: Try do it separate lines so just have it = nothing then do = service.files... on another

Comment: @K.Madden That's what I showed in the last comment. used a | (pipe) to show that command is in another line.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
Try
            Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)
            request.Upload()
            Dim responsefile = request.ResponseBody
            If responsefile.Id.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
               MsgBox(responsefile.Id.ToString) '-----Error catch here 
            Else
               request.Upload()
               responsefile = request.ResponseBody
               MsgBox(responsefile.Id.ToString)
            End If
Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
        Return Nothing 
End Try
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).